# This PC is gone from my file explorer navigation pane and is empty when I view it

Tags: windows-10, windows-explorer

I am using Microsoft Windows 10 Enterprise (Version: 10.0.17134, Build: 17134), Disk managment, and viewing the navigation pane of the File Explorer it is not there. Gone.

[image: navigation pane of the file explorer]

When I try to go to This PC with the path bar I see this folder is empty. I am wondering why this has happened and if there is a fix for this issue.

[image: This folder is empty]

[image]

Comment: How many individual HDDs are connected to your computer?

Comment: Its a laptop  only 1 ssd 250gb

Comment: I assume that, prior to you noticing this behavior, "This PC" worked as expected?

Comment: You are viewing Quick Access section which is not This PC. This PC is actually a section of Desktop in the navigation pane.
In Explorer - Click View tab > Navigation Pane > Show all folders

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are viewing Quick Access section which is not This PC. This PC is actually a section of Desktop in the navigation pane. In Explorer - Click View tab > Navigation Pane > Show all folders.

To restore This PC icon you need to modify registry:

1. Find the key
   *HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID{20D04FE0-3AEA-1069-A2D8-08002B30309D}\ShellFolder*
2. If you have not already, you will need to first change the owner of
   the ShellFolder registry key in the left pane to be the
   **Administrators** group (by default it's SYSTEM).
3. If you have not already, you will need to second set permissions of
   the ShellFolder registry key in the left pane to "Allow" the
   Administrators group "**Full control**".
4. In the right pane of ShellFolder, right click or press and hold on
   **Attributes**, click/tap on Delete, and click/tap on Yes to confirm.
5. If you have a 64-bit Windows 10, open
   *HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Classes\CLSID{20D04FE0-3AEA-1069-A2D8-08002B30309D}\ShellFolder*
6. Repeat the steps 2, 3 and 4 for this key as well.
7. Restart PC.